# Email the value of a dropdown in PHPMailer

Tags: select, phpmailer

I'm at a loss. Can anyone clue me in as to how to send the value of a select box in an email using PHPMailer? Thank you greatly.

In my sendEmail.php:

```
$country = (implode("," , $_POST['country']));
```

In my index.php:

```html
<form id="myForm">

<label>Country</label>
            <select id="country" name="country[]" class="select">
                <option value="" name="country[]">-Select-</option>
                <option value="United States" name="country[]">United States</option>
                <option value="Canada" name="country[]">Canada</option>
         </select>

<button type="button" onclick="sendEmail()" value="Send An Email">Submit</button> 
        </form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendEmail() {
           var select = $('select#country');
            
            if (isNotEmpty(country)) {
                $.ajax({
                   url: 'sendEmail.php',
                   method: 'POST',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   data: {
                       
country: country.val()

                   }, success: function (response) {
                        window.location = "success.html";//redirects to another page
                   }
                });
            }
        }

        function isNotEmpty(caller) {
            if (caller.val() == "") {
                caller.css('border', '1px solid red');
                return false;
            } else
                caller.css('border', '');

            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: So if you're not receiving the contents of your select in `$_REQUEST`, what *are* you getting? PHPMailer isn't involved with this at all - it just sends what you give it, so you need to be sure you're getting what you expect first, and only then try using it in email. Perhaps check out [the JS example included with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform-ajax.phps).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. In the example provided, the select box is used to populate the sending address. I have not located an example for simply getting the dropdown value, passing it through the ajax call and then into the HTML email Body. I'm referencing this tutorial in my code: https://www.codingsnow.com/2021/01/create-php-send-email-contact-form.html

Comment: So what do you get in `$_REQUEST`, for example if you do `var_dump($_REQUEST)`? (you'll see it in the details of the request in your browser's inspector, since it's an Ajax request and not a page load)

Comment: Thank you for the clue. I was finally able to get my drop down result in the email body with the help of the link provided.